# On reconfiguring hdajackretask after a clean install of 16.04 'Apply Now' to test would fail yet installing 'Boot Override' was successful

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I performed a clean install of 16.04 yesterday and ran into a strange issue.
I've followed this process in the past - https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/17sov5/howto_beats_audio_hp_laptop_speakers_on/ and it worked with no issues at all.
I ran into an issue which is actually dealt with in the guide -
Issue 1: At step 8, a few seconds after clicking "Apply" I would get the message:

```
tee: /sys/class/sound/hwC0D0/reconfig: Device or resource busy
```

And Google pointed me to a bug[1] where David Henningsson himself says[2]:

```
You probably need to kill pulseaudio:

echo autospawn = no >> ~/.pulse/client.conf killall pulseaudio

Also check with

sudo fuser -v /dev/snd/*

for other processes currently using sound cards.
```

Doing this worked but then I ran into this issue -
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261307/hdajackretask-tee-sys-class-sound-hwc1d0-reconfig-no-such-device

I searched and couldn't find any resolutions for that particular issue, that post was all I found.
In the end, I took a gamble and just applied boot override and it worked after a restart.  All speakers working correctly.

My question is what is going on when Apply Now so I can test is failing, but just actually doing it without testing actually worked?

Thanks, Chopper

Answer (score 2):

Apply [this patch](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/tiwai/sound.git/commit/?id=addacd801e1638f41d659cb53b9b73fc14322cb1).

Or just wait a couple of days for final [4.6](https://lkml.org/lkml/2016/5/12/500).